# How to disable the default context menu on a text area in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

By default the spark TextArea has a built in ContextMenu with 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'Delete' etc. options.

I want to replace this ContextMenu with a custom one but I'm having a problem with disabling the default one.

After adding a custom one also in first time I am getting the default ContextMenu then from second time I am getting the custom ContextMenu.

I am using the following codes for textarea :

```
<s:TextArea id="txtArea" width="100%" height="100%" borderVisible="false" focusAlpha="0.01" 
            verticalScrollPolicy="off" selectionHighlighting="always" styleName="TextBox"
            needsSoftKeyboard="true" focusRect="false" buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" mouseChildren="true"/>
```

And using the following codes for adding custom ContextMenu to text area at right mouse down :

```
eventMap.mapListener( view.txtArea , MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN ,onRightMouseDown);

private function onRightMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var item1:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Cancel", true);
        var item2:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("Select", true);

        var contextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
        contextMenu.customItems.push(item1);
        contextMenu.customItems.push(item2);

        view.txtArea.contextMenu = contextMenu;
    }
```

But I don't know why default ContextMenu is coming at first time.

So anybody have an idea why it is happening or where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the original context menu the first time is because you're not turning it off until after the first right click has happened. You're also needlessly rebuilding the context menu every time there is a right click.

To fix this, you need to take the code you have in your onRightMouseDown function, and put it into your class constructor or, if you don't have one, anywhere it will be run as soon as the swf is run. This only needs to happen once.

Comment: Hi @Glitcher i have tried to put my codes into class constructor and also tried to put the codes into creation Complete but in both the cases i am getting the default context menu in first right click.

Answer (score 1):

The Following codes resolved my problem:

```
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
contextMenu.clipboardMenu = false;
contextMenu.addItem(new ContextMenuItem("Start Select"));
contextMenu.addItem(new ContextMenuItem("Start Copy"));

(txtArea.textDisplay as RichEditableText).contextMenu = contextMenu;
```

Instead of putting custom context menu directly into textArea control, if we will put on richEditableText as above then that will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've added on whole application

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function (... rest):void
{
})
```

and defaultContextMenu was disabled.